# Select Update and Add or Subtract the values in the row using mysql

Tags: mysql

TABLE tab

```
sl_no    name    marks status 
  1      dude     33     y
  2      dudz     38     y
  3      duda     44     y
  4      dudi     55     y



select marks from tab where name ='dudi';
```

But my question is how to add or subtract a row value[marks]

like i need to add 10 to that selected person's marks

```
update tab set marks ='marks'+10 where name ='dudi';

update tab set marks =(select marks from tab where name ='dudi') +10 where name ='dudi';
```

output

```
  4      dudi     65     y
```

but i am not able to add the marks to it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first syntax should be correct, just don't put marks in quote. It should be:
`update tab set marks = marks + 10 where name ='dudi';`

Answer (score 1):

you cannot `SELECT` and at the same time `UPDATE` the record in just one query BUT you can do it by creating a `STORED PROCEDURE`

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE ViewRecord(IN iName Varchar(50))
      BEGIN
           UPDATE `tab` set `marks` = `marks` + 10 WHERE `name` = iName;
           SELECT `mark`s FROM `tab` WHERE `name` = iName;
      END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

**USAGE**

```
CALL ViewRecord('ViewRecord');
```

**RESULTS**

```
  4      dudi     65     y
```